# Bootstrap 4 typography not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am not using SASS in my project and simply CDN link to include Bootstrap 4

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Below is the HTML

```
<div class=" my-text">
    some text
    </div>
```

But below CSS is having not changing style of text:

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
  .my-text {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
  .my-text {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
  .my-text {
    font-size: 2.6rem;
  }
}
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: It will not work like this. For using these `mixins` you need to add full stack of `bootstrap.scss` files and use `scss` complier to compile `scss files` to your `custom.css`. For more info read [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#sass)

Comment: I've made a small boilerplate to easily setup Bootstrap SCSS compiling. See: https://gist.github.com/Klooven/39e0143d63b5f4efca34c994e94770fa

Comment: Thank you Jyoti and Klooven. That makes it clear now and answers my question.